# Arabic value does not work in jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have one demo code where I have three jsp named `arabic1.jsp`, `arabic2.jsp`, `arabic3.jsp` and one servlet named `ArabicServlet`.

Inside `arabic1.jsp` I have one textbox where I entered arabic value and submitted the page by calling `ArabicServlet` servlet, which forward same content to `arabic2.jsp`, where I have displayed the same content inside textbox which is correctly displayed.

Now I have one link on `arabic2.jsp` to forward request on `arabic3.jsp` using same servlet and content, here on `arabic3.jsp` I have displayed same arabic content inside textbox but I got wrong characters.

I am entering value on first jsp as محمد , It is shown on third jsp as ÙØ­ÙØ¯

arabic1.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/test/ArabicServlet" method="post">
                <table name="tbl1" id="tbl1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="page" name="page" value="1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        Name :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="arabic" name="arabic">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" id="arabic" name="arabic">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

arabic2.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <html>
        <head>
            <%
            Map map = (Hashtable)request.getAttribute("arabic");
            String arabicvalue = (String)map.get("arabicmap");
            System.out.println("Arabic Value on jsp = "+arabicvalue);
            String url = "/test/ArabicServlet?page=2&arabicvalue="+arabicvalue;
            %>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/test/ArabicServlet" method="post">
                <table name="tbl1" id="tbl1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name : 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="arabic" name="arabic" value="<%=arabicvalue%>">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<%=url%>"> Test </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

arabic3.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <%
            Map map = (Hashtable)request.getAttribute("arabic");
            String arabicvalue = (String)map.get("arabicmap");
            System.out.println("Arabic Value on jsp = "+arabicvalue);
            String url = "/test/ArabicServlet?page=2&arabicvalue="+arabicvalue;
            %>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/test/ArabicServlet" method="post">
                <table name="tbl1" id="tbl1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name : 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="arabic" name="arabic" value="<%=arabicvalue%>">
                        </td>   
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

ArabicServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String page = request.getParameter("page");
    System.out.println("Page Number = "+page);

    if(page.equals("1")){
        String arabic = (String)request.getParameter("arabic");
        System.out.println("Arabic Value from first page = "+arabic);

        Map map = new java.util.Hashtable();
        map.put("arabicmap",arabic);
        request.setAttribute("arabic",map);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("arabic2.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }else{
        String arabic = (String)request.getParameter("arabicvalue");
        Map map = new java.util.Hashtable();
        map.put("arabicmap",arabic);
        request.setAttribute("arabic",map);
        System.out.println("Arabic Value from first page = "+arabic);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("arabic3.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to print the value in your console when you click link in arabic2.jsp.

Comment: Can you post an example of your "asserted output" and produced output?

Comment: I am entering value on first jsp as محمد , It is shown on third jsp as ÙØ­ÙØ¯

Comment: URL parameters must be encoded. Use URLEncoder, or better, avoid scriptlets and use the JSTL (`<c:url>` and `<c:param>` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve similar problem by putting these lines in my code:

```
  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```